# How do I make a live text feed for announcements in my app?

Tags: ios, text, feed, live

I would like to add a text feed to my iOS app. Basically, it would just be an updatable UITextView or UIScrollView that would display announcements/news (not an actual news or RSS feed though) on the home page. I want to be able to update this field remotely from my computer to give it a set number of messages/announcements to display one after another in a loop. I don't want to have to update the app to manually add them in via Xcode. I only know Objective-C.

How would I do this? I can't seem to find any tutorials for it. Maybe I'm just not searching in the right way. Can someone refer me to a guide or tutorial or even just a GitHub project I could implement? Thanks.

Edit: I see that a similar question has been asked after all, but I still don't understand the answer given. I'm still new to coding apps so I don't know how to use "initWithContentsFromURL." The person clearly knew what they were doing and so they did not get further explanation. Are there any good guides on how to implement this? I understand you would need to set up a website to store the data, but I'm not quite sure how you would do that. An example of the whole process of setting up the website to store this data and then retrieve it with the function would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Look at push notification APN, there is a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) for how to implement push notification

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I only want this to be displayed while in the app. I do need to figure out push notifications though eventually so thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

If the messages will only be displayed while the user is inside the app, there is no need for push notifications (which will also allow you to contact the user when the app is closed). The app can simply check with a remote server for the most updated content that needs to be displayed whenever the user launches the app (or whenever he/she enters the screen, or once a day - depending on how often you plan to update that info).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. How would I set up this server and what code would I need to add to my app? I can't really understand how to do this without any example code though. If you could link me to some tutorial or explain further that would be great!

Comment: The ideal way would be to set up a server but that may include a lot of overhead. If all you need to do is update this specific data, you can put a text file at a constant URL and have your app download that file and parse it's content every once in a while. Another option would be to use one of the ready made "servers" such as parse.com, which also provide code for the client side and make the integration with their server very easy to implement and maintain.

Comment: It's important to mention, however, that services such as Parse, while making your life a whole lot easier for simpler purposes as the one you're describing here, are not recommended for cases in which a you also have some logic on your server side and are not just using it to store data and access it from various clients. In these cases it's recommended to put in the time and the effort to setup a real server or use more advanced services such as Google App Engine.